# Creating new divs with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, onclick

I have these six static divs in my page and I want to create a button that updates a variable and adds a new div to the page. This is what I have so far:

```
function addSlot(){
   maxChecks = maxChecks+1;
   $("#list").append("<div id ='member7' class='member'></div>");
}
```

So this adds a div but the problem is the new div is always going to have an id of 'member7'. How do I make so that the next time the button is clicked, the next new div is member8, then member9, etc.?

Comment: Is maxchecks defined in the function scope? Can it be used to increment the id number? `div id = 'member' + maxChecks`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this :

```
function addSlot(){
   maxChecks = maxChecks+1;
   var count = jQuery('.member').length;
   var div_id = count + 1;
   $("#list").append("<div id ='member" + div_id + "' class='member'></div>");
}
```

Get the total count of div having class 'member', then do +1 in the DIV id.

Answer (score 2):

It's simple:

```
function addSlot( i ){
  maxChecks = maxChecks+1;
  $("#list").append("<div id ='member" + i + "' class='member'></div>");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This isn't really a jQuery issue; you just need a counter outside the `addSlot` method:

```
var counter = 1;
function addSlot(){
   maxChecks = maxChecks+1;
   $("#list").append("<div id ='member" + (counter++) + "' class='member'></div>");
}
```

Obviously that isn't the only way to do it. See [Nishu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11125069/105570), for example, if you want the ID to always be consistent with the number of member divs.

Answer (score 1):

This will cache the count within the function itself, no matter the calling context, instead of assigning the count to a global variable.

```
function addSlot(){
   var count = (addSlot.count || 0) + 1;
   $("#list").append("<div id='member" + count + "' class='member'></div>");
   addSlot.count = count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

or

```
function addSlot(){
   maxChecks = maxChecks+1;
   $("#list").append("<div id ='member" + ( $('.member').length + 1) + "' class='member'></div>");
}
```

Comment: Might want to scope the `$('.member').length` check to `#list .member` just in case the class is used elsewhere.